# Rails ActiveRecord - Users behave as Team after migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a users and a teams table. The users table has a column called team_id. But now the goal is to allow users to have multiple teams.

So I created the user_teams table using migrations like so:

```
class CreateUserteams < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :user_teams do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :team_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

And my code is as follows:

> models/user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

#belongs_to :team

# should now have multiple teams
has_many :user_teams
has_many :teams, through: :user_teams
```

> models/team.rb

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord

has_many :members, foreign_key: "team_id", class_name: "User"

has_many :user_teams
has_many :users, through: :user_teams
```

> models/user_teams.rb (new file)

```
class UserTeam < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :team
end
```

(This works fine) To invite a user to join a team I send him an invite and if he accepts, I add him to the new users_team table using:

> controllers/team_invites_controller.br

```
    def accept
    user = @team_invite.user
    @team_invite.update(status: TeamInvite.statuses[:accepted])
    user.team_id = @team_invite.team_id
    user.company_id = @team_invite.team.company_id
    user.teams << Team.find(user.team_id)
    user.save(:validate => false)


    respond_to do |format|
      if user.shadow?
        format.html {
          redirect_to new_user_registration_path({
            :email => user.email,
            :role => user.main_role,
          })
        }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to dashboard_root_path, notice: 'Invite accepted' }
      end
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

The problem is, now "user" somehow became a Team and not a User, and it broke all of the code using "user.something". Also because of this I cannot access User methods because "user" is no longer a User but a Team.

For example, now:

```
<% if user.photo.exists? %>
```

gives:

> undefined method `photo' for Team:0x00007f381dea4708

Or:

```
<% if current_user.teams.members.count > 1 %>
```

gives:

> undefined method `members' for
>   Team::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x00007f3845954eb0 Did you mean? member?

Why does users.something now behaves as a team? I already re-did migrations and got the same error. Any idea how thatvhappened and how to fix it? How can I access users properties and methods correctly?
Thank you

**EDIT**
On

```
<% if user.photo.exists? %>
```

it's meant to display the image of another user and it gives the undefined method `photo' error. But if I use (although I don't want to)

```
<% if current_user.photo.exists? %>
```

It works. How come?

Comment: It *might* help if you show the code (by editing your question with the `edit` link right below the tags) around where you're doing `user.teams << Team.find(user.team_id)`.

Comment: @jvillian I've edited the code. Although I don't think that's the problem since I can invite people in. The problem is the association between users and teams.

Comment: Why do you still hold the column team_id in users table?
`user.team_id = @team_invite.team_id`

Comment: @ShiraElitzur I will rename it to favorite_team_id latter.

Comment: Can you provide more context around `user.photo.exists?` which gives the error?

Comment: I'ts located in app/views/users/_photo.html.erb and it was just an example of the error's I'm getting. If I define every method in team.rb it works fine but it's not how it's supposed to be. A team can't have a photo. At least it does not make sense to me, but I could wrong on this...

Answer (score 0):

Your users have multiple `teams` and thus `current_user.teams` is not a `Team` anymore, it's a collection proxy, to access individual teams from there, depending on your logic you can use:

```
<% if current_user.teams.any?{|team| team.members.count > 1 } %>
```

(note that this code may be inefficient if there're many teams)